# error installing chainladder package on python

Tags: python-3.x, math, package, data-science

Am using **python** 3.10.10 on **kaggle** to make **chainladder and mack models** over this data matrix in relation with Provisioning for non-life insurance ( actuariat ) :

Triangle :

[3209, 1163, 39, 17, 7, 21]

[3367, 1292, 37, 24, 10, 0]

[3871, 1474, 53, 22, 0, 0]

[4239, 1678, 103, 0, 0, 0]

[4929, 1865, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[5217, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

But am having an error installing the **chainladder package** which displays the followng error messgae :

*WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7db48811b850>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/chainladder/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7db48811bb80>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/chainladder/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7db48811be20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/chainladder/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7db48811bfd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/chainladder/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7db487f601c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/chainladder/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement chainladder (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for chainladder
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.*

Her's the code am using for the **chainladder** model :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from chainladder import Triangle, validate_model

# Définir le triangle de paiement
triangle = np.array([
  [3209, 1163, 39, 17, 7, 21],
  [3367, 1292, 37, 24, 10, np.nan],
  [3871, 1474, 53, 22, np.nan, np.nan],
  [4239, 1678, 103, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
  [4929, 1865, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
  [5217, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
])

# Convertir le triangle en objet de classe "Triangle"
tri = Triangle(triangle)

# Appliquer le modèle chainladder
cl = tri.ultimate()

# Afficher les réserves et les facteurs de développement
reserves = cl.ibnr
development_factors = cl.latest_development

print("Réserves :")
print(reserves)

print("Facteurs de développement :")
print(development_factors)

# Calculer les paiements cumulatifs
cumulative_payments = tri.cumulative()

# Calculer les paiements incrémentaux
incremental_payments = tri.incremental()

# Afficher les paiements cumulatifs
print("Paiements cumulatifs :")
print(cumulative_payments)

# Afficher les paiements incrémentaux
print("Paiements incrémentaux :")
print(incremental_payments)

# Vérifier les hypothèses du modèle
model_hypotheses = validate_model(tri)

print("Vérification des hypothèses du modèle :")
print(model_hypotheses)

# Afficher la matrice de paiement triangulaire
print("Triangle de paiement :")
print(triangle)

# Afficher le graphique du triangle de paiement
plt.figure()
tri.plot(title="Triangle de paiement")

# Afficher le graphique des réserves
plt.figure()
reserves.plot(title="Réserves")

# Afficher le graphique des facteurs de développement
plt.figure()
development_factors.plot(title="Facteurs de développement")

# Afficher le graphique des paiements cumulatifs
plt.figure()
cumulative_payments.plot(title="Paiements cumulatifs")

# Afficher le graphique des paiements incrémentaux
plt.figure()
incremental_payments.plot(title="Paiements incrémentaux")

plt.show()
```

And for **Mack** :

```
import numpy as np
from chainladder import Triangle, MackChainLadder

# Define the payment triangle
triangle = np.array([
  [3209, 1163, 39, 17, 7, 21],
  [3367, 1292, 37, 24, 10, np.nan],
  [3871, 1474, 53, 22, np.nan, np.nan],
  [4239, 1678, 103, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
  [4929, 1865, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
  [5217, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
])

# Convert the triangle into a Triangle object
tri = Triangle(triangle)

# Apply the Mack model
mack_model = MackChainLadder(tri)

# Get the parameter estimates
estimated_parameters = mack_model.param_

# Get the variance (sigma squared)
variance = mack_model.sigma2_

# Get the MSEP
msep = mack_model.MSEP_

# Get the percentage error
percentage_error = mack_model.Percent_Error_

# Print the parameter estimates
print("Parameter estimates:")
print(estimated_parameters)

# Print the variance (sigma squared)
print("Variance (sigma squared):")
print(variance)

# Print the MSEP
print("MSEP:")
print(msep)

# Print the percentage error
print("Percentage error:")
print(percentage_error)

# Get the cumulative payments
cumulative_payments = mack_model.ultimate_

# Print the cumulative payments
print("Cumulative payments:")
print(cumulative_payments)
```

I tried upgrading pip using the following command : `pip3 install --upgrade pip`     but it's not helping

am waiting forward a helping alternative which can solve this problem on my ubuntu 20.04.6 laptop

Thanks in advance